# libusb in linux

Tags: linux, usb, kernel, device-driver, libusb

I like to do usb programming with libusb.
I installed it using

```
$ apt-get install libusb-1.0
```

and then

```
$ apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

but after I tried to use it in c code, there are compiler errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

int main(){
  usb_init(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler errors are:

```
**/tmp/ccgCZXTu.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `usb_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

This is a linker error, you're not telling the compiler that your code needs to be linked with the libusb library.

A mere `#include` in C is not enough for this, all it does is make available the declarations needed to talk about the library's code, it doesn't in any way reference the code itself.

Add `$(pkg-config --libs libusb)` to your GCC command line.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to using

```
pkg-config --libs libusb-1.0
```

for libusb-1.0

Answer (score -2):

You may include it as :

```
#include </usr/local/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```